FastAPI Error: HTTPBasic.__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
I am trying to create a simple WebSocket app with authentication using FastAPI, but after adding the authentication I face issues,
The /{id} request passes, but the WebSocket connection /ws/{client_id} gets failed due to the following error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\websockets\websockets_impl.py", line 240, in run_asgi
    result = await self.app(self.scope, self.asgi_receive, self.asgi_send)
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 69, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 123, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 151, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 65, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 756, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 776, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 373, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 96, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, session)(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 94, in app
    await func(session)
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 338, in app
    solved_result = await solve_dependencies(
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\fastapi\dependencies\utils.py", line 572, in solve_dependencies
    solved_result = await solve_dependencies(
  File "D:\Installations\envs\chat-app\lib\site-packages\fastapi\dependencies\utils.py", line 600, in solve_dependencies
    solved = await call(**sub_values)
TypeError: HTTPBasic.__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
INFO:     connection open
INFO:     connection closed

Code:
app = FastAPI()
security = HTTPBasic()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_connections: List[WebSocket] = []

    async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.accept()
        self.active_connections.append(websocket)

    def disconnect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        self.active_connections.remove(websocket)

    async def send_personal_message(self, message: str, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.send_text(message)

    async def broadcast(self, message: str, websocket: WebSocket) :
        for connection in self.active_connections:
            if (connection == websocket):
                continue
            await connection.send_text(message)

connectionmanager = ConnectionManager()

def get_current_username(
    credentials: Annotated[HTTPBasicCredentials, Depends(security)],
):
    is_correct_username, is_correct_password= validate_user(credentials.username.encode("utf8"),credentials.password.encode("utf8"))
    
    if not (is_correct_username and is_correct_password):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Basic"},
        )
    return credentials.username

@app.get("/{id}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def read_user(id: int,  username: Annotated[str, Depends(get_current_username)], request: Request):
    # Render the HTML template
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})


@app.websocket("/ws/{client_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(
        websocket: WebSocket, client_id: int, username: Annotated[str, Depends(get_current_username)], request: Request):
    # accept connections
    await connectionmanager.connect(websocket)
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            await connectionmanager.send_personal_message(f"You : {data}", websocket)
            await connectionmanager.broadcast(f"Client #{client_id}: {data}", websocket)

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        connectionmanager.disconnect(websocket)
        await connectionmanager.broadcast(f"Client #{client_id} left the chat")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=8000)

Before adding the authentication mechanism it was working fine.
Even though I added the Request parameter, still I am getting this error.

The request object is not available in a WebSocket route, but it is in HTTP route which is why the GET request works with the request object.
Plus, you're not even using the request object in the websocket_endpoint function, remove request from the parameter list.
You need to find some way to handle Web Socket authentication.
Here is an example of Web Socket authentication
from fastapi import WebSocket, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasicCredentials
import base64

async def authenticate_websocket(websocket: WebSocket):
    auth_header = websocket.headers.get("Authorization")
    if not auth_header:
        await websocket.close(code=status.WS_1008_POLICY_VIOLATION)
        return None

    try:
        scheme, credentials = auth_header.split()
        if scheme.lower() != "basic":
            await websocket.close(code=status.WS_1008_POLICY_VIOLATION)
            return None

        decoded = base64.b64decode(credentials).decode("ascii")
        username, _, password = decoded.partition(":")
        is_correct_username, is_correct_password = validate_user(username.encode("utf8"), password.encode("utf8"))

        if not (is_correct_username and is_correct_password):
            await websocket.close(code=status.WS_1008_POLICY_VIOLATION)
            return None

        return username
    except Exception:
        await websocket.close(code=status.WS_1008_POLICY_VIOLATION)
        return None

Now, we can modify your websocket_endpoint function to use this new authentication method:
@app.websocket("/ws/{client_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, client_id: int):
    username = await authenticate_websocket(websocket)
    if not username:
        return  # WebSocket connection is already closed if authentication failed

    await connectionmanager.connect(websocket)
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            await connectionmanager.send_personal_message(f"You : {data}", websocket)
            await connectionmanager.broadcast(f"Client #{client_id} ({username}): {data}", websocket)
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        connectionmanager.disconnect(websocket)
        await connectionmanager.broadcast(f"Client #{client_id} ({username}) left the chat")

You were close, but web sockets does NOT have access to the request object.
HUGE caveat
If this is meant to go into production, PLEASE PLEASE use JWT Auth. You can read more about that at this GitHub link.
